# Stack trace with fs/promises and async..await

Tags: node.js, error-handling, async-await, fs, stack-trace

I have a problem that is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61155350/why-theres-no-stack-trace-in-node-fs-rmdir-error) and described in [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30944). There are no stack traces in errors that come from `fs/promises` when used with async..await, and no way to determine where the error happened.

Given the app:

*foo.js*

```
const { bar } = require('./bar');

async function foo() {
  await bar();
}


(async () => {
  await foo();
})().catch(console.error);
```

*bar.js*

```
const fs = require('fs/promises');

exports.bar = async function bar() {
  await fs.readFile('some');
}
```

When it runs like `node foo.js`, this results in an error with no stack trace:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '...\some'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '...\\some'
}
```

Where `error.stack` contains 'ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '...\some'.

When it runs like `node --stack_trace_limit=100 -r trace foo.js` with `trace` package, like it's suggested in linked sources, this results in this stack trace:

[image: stack trace]

Notice that internal entries are grayed and can be filtered out.

This `node --stack_trace_limit=100 -r trace -r clarify foo.js` with `trace` and `clarify` packages results in this output:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '...\some'
    at ...\foo.js:8:2
    at Object.<anonymous> (...\foo.js:10:3) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '...\\some',
  [Symbol(originalCallSite)]: [],
  [Symbol(mutatedCallSite)]: [ CallSite {}, CallSite {} ]
}
```

The problem is that *bar.js* isn't mentioned in all of the outputs.

My intention is to provide clean error output with no internal entries and the exact location where the error occurs, i.e. line number in bar.js.

What are possible solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

So close :)

Edit:
based on [fs/promise issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30944),
it's a known issue, and could be worked-around on demand, as suggested below.

> This node --stack_trace_limit=100 -r trace -r clarify foo.js
> with trace and clarify packages results in this output:
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '...\some'
> at ...\foo.js:8:2
> at Object. (...\foo.js:10:3) {
> errno: -4058,
> code: 'ENOENT',
> syscall: 'open',
> path: '...\some',
> [Symbol(originalCallSite)]: [],
> [Symbol(mutatedCallSite)]: [ CallSite {}, CallSite {} ]
> }
>
> The problem is that **bar.js isn't mentioned** in all of the outputs.

In addition for using trace/clarify,
do try/catch directly on fs.readFile call (bar.js)

```js
const fs = require('fs/promises');

exports.bar = async () => {
    try {
        await fs.readFile('some');
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

```shell
$ node --stack_trace_limit=100 -r trace -r clarify foo.js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'some'
    at emitInitNative (node:internal/async_hooks:205:43)
    at emitInitNative (node:internal/async_hooks:205:43)
    at emitInitScript (node:internal/async_hooks:495:3)
    at promiseInitHook (node:internal/async_hooks:325:3)
    at promiseInitHookWithDestroyTracking (node:internal/async_hooks:329:3)
    at Object.readFile (node:internal/fs/promises:786:24)

    at exports.bar (/home/lz/code/stackover/bar.js:6:18)

    at foo (/home/lz/code/stackover/foo.js:4:11)
    at /home/lz/code/stackover/foo.js:9:15
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/lz/code/stackover/foo.js:13:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'some'
}
```

You can also try sync read file.

Comment: The problem is that this requires to use try..catch in every place where fs is used, something I'd prefer to avoid at all cost, or to use my own wrappers for fs which is very awkward. The problem with this snippet is that it doesn't rethrow an error like another answer suggests. The caller is supposed to be aware of the error. sync methods are not an option at this point because I wend with fs/promises for non-blocking FS ops, but now I see the problem with using it as a rule of thumb.

Comment: @EstusFlask i feel like wrapper is the way, could be awkward, but there are some pros to it - you can switch/experiment fs implementation/lib from a single place in your code.
from what I read [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30944#issuecomment-565570140), it is a known bug, unresolved for performance reasons which might be relevant in your case.
loosing some details from the error for a gain in performance is a small price to pay.

Comment: I'd expect that there's an existing wrapper library that does that, but the ones I know like fs-extra seem to fall back to native implementation. Any way, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Since the root cause of your problem is that `fs/promises` `Error`s have no stack by design, why simply not throwing your own when you need stack details?

More than this I can suggest to avoid using the `catch` method of promises and to use only the **async/await** construct.

*foo.js*

```
const { bar } = require('./bar');

async function foo() {
  await bar();
}

(async function main() {
  try {
    await foo();
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
})();
```

*bar.js*

```
const fs = require('fs/promises');

exports.bar = async function bar() {
  try{
    await fs.readFile('some');
  } catch(e) {
    throw new Error(e.message);
  }
};
```

This gives following result:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'some'
    at bar (/home/me/test/bar.js:7:11)
    at async foo (/home/me/test/foo.js:4:3)
    at async main (/home/me/test/foo.js:9:5)
```

Probably you neither need to use `trace` and/or `clarify`, but of course you are still free to use them to alter the stack trace at your needs.

Comment: I hoped for a more general solution. The problem is that this requires to use try..catch in every place where fs is used, something I'd prefer to avoid at all cost, or to use my own wrappers for fs which is very awkward. Any way, I'll likely use `new Error` as a quick fix and will restrain myself from using fs/promises in non-critical parts in future. `.catch` was used as a catch-all for AIIFE, I don't think it affects the way error handling works here.

Comment: I know @EstusFlask : very bad! ATM I think there is no better solution than writing your own wrappers for the functions you need to trace. As a catch-all mechanism I use an `async function` strictly fully contained in a `try/catch` block for all entry points of my programs (the _main_ function, event handles, etc...).